# "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." in xml file

Tags: xml, spring

I am new to xml and spring. Following is spring-servlet file. I have copied it from following link : [spring-servlet.xml](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/)

File code is as follows :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">     
    <property name="viewClass">         
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>     
    </property> 
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">     
    <property name="definitions">         
        <list>             
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>         
        </list>     
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have a root element. Your XML looks like

```
<bean>...</bean>
<bean>...</bean>
```

whereas I'd expect a root e.g.

```
<beans>
   <bean>...</bean>
   <bean>...</bean>
</beans>
```

XML documents have to have a *root* node - a top-level node below which you can have multiple branches.

From the linked tutorial:

> Open the spring-servlet.xml from WEB-INF folder and add following code
>   between `<beans> </beans>` tag.

I think that's the bit you missed :-)